# Long-Short Portfolio Calculation in R

Tags: r, quantmod

I would like to know how to construct a Long-Short portfolio in R as is typical in financial literature.

Say I have the following data:

Head():

```
# A tibble: 6 x 4
# Groups:   assets [1]
  assets  returns    id quantile
  <fct>     <dbl> <int> <chr>   
1 AEIS   -0.157       1 1       
2 AEIS    0.107       2 1       
3 AEIS    0.140       3 1       
4 AEIS   -0.111       4 1       
5 AEIS   -0.160       5 1       
6 AEIS   -0.00566     6 1
```

Tail():

```
# A tibble: 6 x 4
# Groups:   assets [1]
  assets returns    id quantile
  <fct>    <dbl> <int> <chr>   
1 GIB     0.0742   110 8       
2 GIB     0.0201   111 8       
3 GIB     0.0255   112 8       
4 GIB     0.0446   113 8       
5 GIB     0.0143   114 8       
6 GIB     0.0537   115 8
```

How does one construct the L-S portfolio such that I long portfolio/quantile `1` and short portfolio/quantile `8`?

Data/Code:

```
library(quantmod)
library(reshape2)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
stocks <- c('AEIS', 'ABC', 'AMGN', 'BBY', 'HRB', 'BKE', 'CPLA', 'GIB')
getSymbols(stocks, from = "2010-01-01")

prices.data <- do.call(merge, lapply(stocks, function(x) Cl(get(x))))
returns <- setNames(do.call(cbind, lapply(prices.data, monthlyReturn)), stocks)


data <- returns %>%
  data.frame() %>%
  gather(assets, returns, 1:8, factor_key=TRUE) %>%
  group_by(assets) %>%
  mutate(id = 1:n(),
         quantile = as.numeric(assets))

head(data)
```

Comment: I'm not clear on what your question is. It seems you've identified the quantiles for your assets, and you want to go long quantile 1 and short quantile 8. What else do you want to do to carry out the construction you have in mind? Are you backtesting performance perhaps?

Comment: A lot I see in the literature reports some regressions for each quantile portfolio returns regressed on some Fama French factors SMB, HML MktRF etc. They also add an additional portfolio for a L-S. I am just wondering exactly how they construct these portfolios. Is it just the Quantile 1 returns minus the Quantile 8 returns?

Answer (score 3):

The following code illustrates how to do a LS return calculation (and hopefully assist others keen to see how LS portfolio returns can be calculated).

I show you also qhat the quantile portfolio is all about - it is typically a ranking exercise (by e.g. a factor score), which implies certain stocks are long, and other short based on the score.

Would be great to see if someone can poke holes in the LS calculation below, but my simple check seems to indicate it works well.

```
library(quantmod)
library(reshape2)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
if(!require(tbl2xts)) install.packages("tbl2xts")
if(!require(rmsfuns)) install.packages("rmsfuns")

stocks <- c('AEIS', 'ABC', 'AMGN', 'BBY', 'HRB', 'BKE', 'GIB') # CPLA doesn't fetch
getSymbols(stocks, from = "2016-01-01")

prices.data <- do.call(merge, lapply(stocks, function(x) Cl(get(x))))
returns <- setNames(do.call(cbind, lapply(prices.data, monthlyReturn)), stocks)

FactorInfo <- 
tibble(assets = stocks, FactorScore = rnorm(n = length(stocks)))

data <- 
  returns %>% xts_tbl() %>% 
  gather(assets, returns, -date) %>%
  left_join(., FactorInfo, by = "assets") %>% 
  mutate(RankPctile = percent_rank(FactorScore))

LongStocks <- data %>% select(assets, FactorScore) %>% unique() %>% arrange(FactorScore) %>% head(2) # pick two worst to short, as example
ShortStocks <- data %>% select(assets, FactorScore) %>% unique() %>% arrange(FactorScore) %>% tail(2) # pick two best to long, as example

Long_Port <- data %>% filter(assets %in% unique(LongStocks$assets)) %>%     tbl_xts(cols_to_xts = "returns", spread_by = "assets")
Short_Port <- data %>% filter(assets %in% unique(ShortStocks$assets)) %>% tbl_xts(cols_to_xts = "returns", spread_by = "assets")

# Fully funded long-short position
W_Long <- data %>% filter(assets %in% unique(LongStocks$assets)) %>% filter(date == first(date)) %>% mutate(Weight = 1 / n()) %>% tbl_xts(cols_to_xts = "Weight", spread_by = "assets")
W_Short <- data %>% filter(assets %in% unique(ShortStocks$assets)) %>% filter(date == first(date)) %>% mutate(Weight = -1 / n()) %>% tbl_xts(cols_to_xts = "Weight", spread_by = "assets")

# Now calculate LS portfolio using PerformanceAnalytics:
# I recommend using rmsfuns::Safe_Return.portfolio, a wrapper for PerformanceAnalytics that makes it safer to use:

Port <- cbind(Long_Port, Short_Port)
Port_W <- cbind(W_Long, W_Short)

Port <- 
  rmsfuns::Safe_Return.portfolio(R = Port, weights = Port_W, lag_weights = TRUE, geometric = TRUE, verbose = TRUE)
LS_Port <- Port$returns %>% xts_tbl() %>% summarise(Cum = prod(1+portfolio.returns)) %>% .[[1]]

# Check correctness with direct calculation (can be done if only rebalanced once at the start):
all.equal( bind_rows(Long_Port %>% xts_tbl() %>% gather(assets, Ret, -date) %>% mutate(Weight = 1 / n_distinct(assets)),
                    Short_Port  %>% xts_tbl() %>% gather(assets, Ret, -date) %>% mutate(Weight = -1 / n_distinct(assets))) %>% 
           group_by(assets, Weight) %>% summarise(Ret = prod(1+Ret) - 1) %>% ungroup() %>% summarise(Ret = sum(Ret*Weight)) %>% .[[1]], 

           LS_Port-1)

# To see your daily positions:
LS_Daily <- Port$EOP.Value %>% xts_tbl %>% gather(stocks, eop.val, -date) %>% group_by(date) %>% summarise(return = sum(eop.val)) 

# Of course - you can further rebalance to other positions by adjusting Port_W
```

Comment: is there a chance you have the same code in Python?

Comment: Kidding - don't have it in Python unfortunately no. Time to learn some R :)